# Display a mp4 video in Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview, mp4

I have to show a MP4 video in a Android View.
So, in my layout I added this:

```
<VideoView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView">
    </VideoView>
```

and in my activity I have:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.cloud;
android.net.Uri uri = android.net.Uri.parse(uriPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

But I always get an alert message: can't play this video
and In the log message I see: `E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)`

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

May be the format of the mp4 video you are trying is not support end.